# Unwanted texture at base of ABS print

Tags: print-quality, abs, flashforge-creator

I'm getting close with this print, but I'm seeing some rippling at the base that I can't seem to eliminate (see photo at the end of the post). The model is [here](https://github.com/jpstroop/printer_cam/blob/main/stl/box.stl) if it helps. It seems that the texture evens out above the floor of the box.

I think these are the relevant settings:

- Extruder temp: 240 °C
- Bed temp: 110 °C
- Infill outline overlap: 20 %
- Infill: 40 %, triangles
- Layer height: 0.1 mm
- First layer height and width: 200 %
- Speed: 40.0 mm/s (first layer: 40 %)
- Bottom solid layers: 3
- Top solid layers: 6 (I was getting a lot of [pillowing](https://www.reddit.com/r/3Dprinting/comments/3x94a7/what_causes_bubbling_on_the_top_layer/) with any less; still
  am even with 6)
- Perimeter layers: 6
- Retraction: 1 mm
- Retraction speed: 20 mm/s

The printer is a Flashforge Creator Pro.

[image: print with unwanted texture at base]

Comment: Perhaps [this](/a/13713) answers your question?

Comment: Elephant foot. That's an Elephant foot.

Comment: Interesting. I've seen elephant foot before but not with this kind of texture. So it's probably a combination of first layer width and my Z stop / bed level?  The only thing I'd note is that, while I can't confirm it, it seems like the texture doesn't show up until later in the build. Is that from the extruder pushing down too hard on the print? Anyway, thanks. I'll give it a try tonight.

Comment: It used to happen to me when the Z probe distance was not calibrated properly (too close or too far, cannot remember which one). When I calibrated it it went away. However, the cause of your problems might be different.

Comment: That was it! Re-leveled the bed with a business card rather than a sheet of printer paper, and then reduced the first layer width to 125% and all good.